# Trying to delete a record from a parent entity java class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I have two entity java classes . Now I am trying to Delete a record from parent entity but it was throwing an error : `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; SYS_FK_10142 table: CHILD`.

```
**Parent class**
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @NotBlank
  @Column(name = "data")
  private String data;
  public Long getId()
  {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(Long id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getData()
  {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(String data)
  {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

**Child class**

@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotBlank
  private String model;

  @ManyToOne()
  @OnDelete(action= org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  private Parent parent;

  public Long getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getModel()
  {
    return model;
  }

  public void setModel(String model)
  {
    this.model = model;
  }
}
```

Comment: try also specify `OnUpdate` action.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're deleting the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're deleting a parent record and expecting the associated child records also to be deleted, you may need a bi-directional relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent
{
   ...
   ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE)
   private List<Child> children;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child
{
   ...
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   private Parent parent;


}
```

Comment: iirc, declaring a `CascadeType.REMOVE` is not going to remove the children, but simply removing the relationship.  I believe you need `orphanRemoval=true` if you want the children to be deleted

Comment: @AdrianShum: Your comment is not entirely correct. If you call em.remove(parent) with `CascadeType.REMOVE`, all references to child entities are removed as well. See doc to [REMOVE](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Cascading_Remove_). On the other hand, `orphanRemoval=true` is only necessary, if you want to remove child entities when you simply remove it from the parents collection, e.g. when you call parent.children.remove(child).

Comment: Thanks everyone.. I appreciate it.